# Как называется такой модуль?

Tags: php

Как называется такой модуль? Выделен красным на фото

[image: Здесь]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дорога или "Хлебные крошки" (breadcrumbs)

Answer (score 1):

Breadcrumbs